# FirebaseCore not found

Tags: swift, firebase

> Module 'FirebaseCore' not found

fireBaseCore not found issue after updating pods.

[image]

**But when I change** "@import FirebaseCore;" to "#import "FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h". everything feels working.
File location: Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseCoreInternal.h

**Please help me where I am wrong**.

**Thanks**

Comment: Try using SPM instead of Cocoapods

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not sure I fully agree with the above comment as a 'solution' as SPM has its own set of challenges. To really understand the issue we would need to see the current podfile, know what version of cocoapods is installed (pod --version) and version of XCode. More than likely your pod repo is outdated or there's an issue in the podfile. Should be a simple fix - please update the question with more details (it's also a good idea to tag your question with the Firebase product you're using, Realtime Database, Firestore etc).

Answer (score 0):

For module imports to work, the Podfile should specify `use_frameworks!`

Note that `use_frameworks!` has been required for Firebase since major version  9.